# Is it safe to use python's -S option?

Tags: python

The -S option to python is defined by the documentation as "Disable the import of the module site and the site-dependent manipulations of sys.path that it entails."  I've found that python startup on my machine is more than twice as fast, sometimes *much* more, when I use this option.  For example, on one (slow) machine:

```
$ time python -c 'print "hello"'   
hello
python -c 'print "hello"'  0.14s user 0.03s system 85% cpu 0.204 total

$ time python -Sc 'print "hello"'
hello
python -Sc 'print "hello"'  0.02s user 0.01s system 73% cpu 0.038 total
```

That's a 5.3x speedup.  And it seems to work fine, at least with the scripts I've tried.  What are the disadvantages to using it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's probably not a good idea.  Among other things, it means that the site-packages directory won't be added to the path, so you won't be able to import anything but the standard lib modules:

```
python -Sc "import numpy"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named numpy
```

You can look at `site.py` yourself to see what it's doing.  It's just a module in the regular library directory.  At least on my system, it looks like it does four main things:

- sets up the site-packages paths
- sets the default encoding
- defines a few helper functions for interactive use (`quit` and `help`)
- sets up user-specific site customization

The first one is probably the most critical, as mentioned above.  The second could be important for doing string I/O depending on your system's locale settings (i.e., you may get errors if the default encoding isn't correctly set).  The third is probably not that important.  The last one could be important if you like to have per-user path customizations (letting users have their own personal library directories, etc.).

Comment: Hmm, it sounds like if my program is English-only (ie. lazy) and only relies on basic standard python modules, *not* setting the default encoding could cause *less* problems (fewer surprises with .lower() and whatnot).  So this could be fine when I'm writing some basic scripts that don't do much, but where startup time matters.

Answer (score 3):

The `-S` flag does the following:

> don't imply 'import site' on initialization

This means the module [site](http://docs.python.org/library/site.html) is not imported during initialization of Python. A brief description is that this module *"will append site-specific paths to the module search path and add a few builtins"*. Not doing all this work will indeed make the startup faster.

Using the documentation as a guide, the `-S` flag results in:

- No additional modules added to `sys.path`. You can compare the difference by starting `python` and `python -S` and doing the following in both `import sys; print sys.path`. Many modules won't be available so you won't be able to import them.
- Custom site initialization code won't be run (this can be defined in a module called `sitecustomize`).
- Custom initialization code won't be run (this can be defined in a module called `usercustomize`).

The short answer to your question is: yes, it makes Python startup faster but many modules and customization code won't be available or possible.

If you primarily import your own modules and write your own computations / code then the `-S` flag is fine. But if you have a Python installation with modules installed in different places then you won't be able to use them with the `-S` flag.

Answer (score 2):

You will loose a large chunk of your module search path when you do this:

```
$ python -S
Python 2.6.8 (unknown, Apr 19 2012, 01:24:00) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2335.15.00)] on darwin
>>> import sys
>>> len(sys.path)
9

$ python
Python 2.6.8 (unknown, Apr 19 2012, 01:24:00) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2335.15.00)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> len(sys.path)
26
```

Depending on your system, that can have major consequences as to what modules are available.

Other things that may break are the locale (set to the system default by site.py) and, on windows, some codecs will not be available (they are aliased by site.py).

Comment: This all begs the question: Why do so many things need to go into site-packages?  I'm pretty sure it's not necessary most of the time.  But for some reason, it's traditional to put even code that you might use just once, into site-packages.  It seems to me it would be better to put things that aren't shared by multiple applications under a unique directory in /usr/local or something.

Comment: Because that's the place where modules are supposed to go.  In general if you install some third-party library it goes into the python site packages directory.  Where else should they go?

Comment: If you mean modules that you create yourself for specific projects, then yeah, it's fine not to put those in site-packages.  But when you install a third-party library, it should generally go in site-packages, because if you install some library, it probably means you're going to use it for stuff.  Looking in my site-packages directory I see lots of general-purpose libraries like numpy, scipy, matplotlib, gtk, pygame, pyparsing dabo --- stuff that many Python programs might need to use.